# Connection lost when running SQL query with three quotes in a row

Tags: oracle

Certain SQL queries will cause my connection to freeze and drop after about 20 seconds. This is happening on both an 11g database and a 12c database.

So far, the only thing in common with the offending queries is that they all have multiple groups of quotes, one of the groups has three quotes in a row, i.e. `'''`, and between the groups, there are pipes or hyphens (e.g. `||||`, `--`).

Example output from sqlplus:

```
> exec dbms_output.put_line(q'[ '''--''' ]');
BEGIN dbms_output.put_line(q'[ '''--''' ]'); END;

*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-03113: end-of-file on communication channel
Process ID: 143349
Session ID: 284 Serial number: 51992


Elapsed: 00:00:18.93
```

I am expecting to see `'''--'''`, but the connection is lost instead.

I have replicated the bug in sqlplus 11.2.0.1.0, SQL Developer 4.1.3.20, and Toad 12.6.

This is causing problems when running in packages. A large number of packages have code like this: `'''' || l_varchar2_variable || '''';`. When these packages are being run in, the connection is lost.

Sample list of queries that cause the connection to be dropped:

```
exec dbms_output.put_line(q'['''--''']');
exec dbms_output.put_line(q'['''---''']');
exec dbms_output.put_line(q'['''----''']');
exec dbms_output.put_line(q'['''||||''']');
exec dbms_output.put_line(q'['''||||' ' ']');
exec dbms_output.put_line(q'['''||||' ' ']');
exec dbms_output.put_line(''''||''||'''');
execute immediate(''''||||'''');
execute immediate(''''    ||||    '''');
exec dbms_output.put_line(q'#'''|| ||'''#');
exec dbms_output.put_line(q'[ ||'''||--''' ]');
```

Sample list of queries that *don't* have any problems:

```
exec dbms_output.put_line(q'[ '''' '''' ]');
exec dbms_output.put_line(q'[ ''' || ''' ]');
exec dbms_output.put_line(q'[ ''' | | | | ''' ]');
exec dbms_output.put_line(q'[ ''' - - ''' ]');
exec dbms_output.put_line(q'[ ''' ||| ''' ]');
exec dbms_output.put_line(q'[ ' ' ' |||| ' ' ' ]');
exec dbms_output.put_line(q'[ ''' |||| ]');
exec dbms_output.put_line(q'[ |||| ''' ]');
select ''''||''||'''' from dual;
select '''''||||''''' from dual;
select ''''||'--'||'''' from dual;
```

Setting the following in sqlnet.ora

```
TRACE_LEVEL_CLIENT=16
TRACE_DIRECTORY_CLIENT=c:\_temp
TRACE_FILE_CLIENT=client
TRACE_UNIQUE_CLIENT=ON
TRACE_TIMESTAMP_CLIENT=ON
DIAG_ADR_ENABLED =OFF
```

This is the output from after I hit Return to execute the query:

```
[10-JUL-2017 13:58:33:476] nioqsn: entry
[10-JUL-2017 13:58:33:477] nioqsn: exit
[10-JUL-2017 13:58:33:477] nioqrc: entry
[10-JUL-2017 13:58:33:477] nsbasic_bsd: entry
[10-JUL-2017 13:58:33:477] nsbasic_bsd: tot=0, plen=287.
[10-JUL-2017 13:58:33:477] nttfpwr: entry
[10-JUL-2017 13:58:33:477] nttfpwr: socket 528 had bytes written=287
[10-JUL-2017 13:58:33:477] nttfpwr: exit
[10-JUL-2017 13:58:33:477] nsbasic_bsd: packet dump
[10-JUL-2017 13:58:33:477] nsbasic_bsd: 01 1F 00 00 06 00 00 00  |........|
[10-JUL-2017 13:58:33:477] nsbasic_bsd: 00 00 03 5E 45 21 00 04  |...^E!..|
[10-JUL-2017 13:58:33:477] nsbasic_bsd: 00 00 00 00 00 FE FF FF  |........|
[10-JUL-2017 13:58:33:477] nsbasic_bsd: FF FF FF FF FF 93 00 00  |........|
[10-JUL-2017 13:58:33:477] nsbasic_bsd: 00 FE FF FF FF FF FF FF  |........|
[10-JUL-2017 13:58:33:477] nsbasic_bsd: FF 0D 00 00 00 FE FF FF  |........|
[10-JUL-2017 13:58:33:477] nsbasic_bsd: FF FF FF FF FF FE FF FF  |........|
[10-JUL-2017 13:58:33:477] nsbasic_bsd: FF FF FF FF FF 00 00 00  |........|
[10-JUL-2017 13:58:33:477] nsbasic_bsd: 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00  |........|
[10-JUL-2017 13:58:33:477] nsbasic_bsd: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |........|
[10-JUL-2017 13:58:33:477] nsbasic_bsd: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |........|
[10-JUL-2017 13:58:33:477] nsbasic_bsd: 00 00 00 00 00 FE FF FF  |........|
[10-JUL-2017 13:58:33:477] nsbasic_bsd: FF FF FF FF FF 00 00 00  |........|
[10-JUL-2017 13:58:33:477] nsbasic_bsd: 00 00 00 00 00 FE FF FF  |........|
[10-JUL-2017 13:58:33:477] nsbasic_bsd: FF FF FF FF FF FE FF FF  |........|
[10-JUL-2017 13:58:33:477] nsbasic_bsd: FF FF FF FF FF FE FF FF  |........|
[10-JUL-2017 13:58:33:477] nsbasic_bsd: FF FF FF FF FF 00 00 00  |........|
[10-JUL-2017 13:58:33:477] nsbasic_bsd: 00 00 00 00 00 FE FF FF  |........|
[10-JUL-2017 13:58:33:477] nsbasic_bsd: FF FF FF FF FF FE FF FF  |........|
[10-JUL-2017 13:58:33:477] nsbasic_bsd: FF FF FF FF FF 00 00 00  |........|
[10-JUL-2017 13:58:33:477] nsbasic_bsd: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |........|
[10-JUL-2017 13:58:33:477] nsbasic_bsd: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |........|
[10-JUL-2017 13:58:33:477] nsbasic_bsd: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |........|
[10-JUL-2017 13:58:33:477] nsbasic_bsd: 00 31 42 45 47 49 4E 20  |.1BEGIN.|
[10-JUL-2017 13:58:33:478] nsbasic_bsd: 64 62 6D 73 5F 6F 75 74  |dbms_out|
[10-JUL-2017 13:58:33:478] nsbasic_bsd: 70 75 74 2E 70 75 74 5F  |put.put_|
[10-JUL-2017 13:58:33:478] nsbasic_bsd: 6C 69 6E 65 28 71 27 5B  |line(q'[|
[10-JUL-2017 13:58:33:478] nsbasic_bsd: 27 27 27 2D 2D 27 27 27  |'''--'''|
[10-JUL-2017 13:58:33:478] nsbasic_bsd: 5D 27 29 3B 20 45 4E 44  |]');.END|
[10-JUL-2017 13:58:33:478] nsbasic_bsd: 3B 0A 00 01 00 00 00 01  |;.......|
[10-JUL-2017 13:58:33:478] nsbasic_bsd: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |........|
[10-JUL-2017 13:58:33:478] nsbasic_bsd: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |........|
[10-JUL-2017 13:58:33:478] nsbasic_bsd: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 08  |........|
[10-JUL-2017 13:58:33:478] nsbasic_bsd: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |........|
[10-JUL-2017 13:58:33:478] nsbasic_bsd: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |........|
[10-JUL-2017 13:58:33:478] nsbasic_bsd: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00     |....... |
[10-JUL-2017 13:58:33:478] nsbasic_bsd: exit (0)
[10-JUL-2017 13:58:33:478] nsbasic_brc: entry: oln/tot=0
[10-JUL-2017 13:58:33:478] nttfprd: entry
[10-JUL-2017 13:58:52:377] ntt2err: entry
[10-JUL-2017 13:58:52:377] ntt2err: exit
[10-JUL-2017 13:58:52:377] nttfprd: exit
[10-JUL-2017 13:58:52:377] nserror: entry
[10-JUL-2017 13:58:52:377] nserror: nsres: id=0, op=68, ns=12535, ns2=12560; nt[0]=505, nt[1]=60, nt[2]=0; ora[0]=0, ora[1]=0, ora[2]=0
[10-JUL-2017 13:58:52:377] nsbasic_brc: exit: oln=0, dln=0, tot=0, rc=-1
[10-JUL-2017 13:58:52:377] nioqrc:  wanted 1 got 0, type 0
[10-JUL-2017 13:58:52:377] nioqper:  error from nioqrc
[10-JUL-2017 13:58:52:377] nioqper:    ns main err code: 12535
[10-JUL-2017 13:58:52:377] nioqper:    ns (2)  err code: 12560
[10-JUL-2017 13:58:52:377] nioqper:    nt main err code: 505
[10-JUL-2017 13:58:52:377] nioqper:    nt (2)  err code: 60
[10-JUL-2017 13:58:52:377] nioqper:    nt OS   err code: 0
[10-JUL-2017 13:58:52:377] nioqer: entry
[10-JUL-2017 13:58:52:377] nioqer:  incoming err = 12151
[10-JUL-2017 13:58:52:377] nttaddr2bnd: entry
[10-JUL-2017 13:58:52:377] snlinGetNameInfo: entry
[10-JUL-2017 13:58:52:377] snlinGetNameInfo: exit
```

Note the time change from 13:58:33 to 13:58:52 - this is where the connection is lost.

Thank you for your time!

Comment: This `'[ '''--''' ]'` is an invalid string for oracle you see, every two consecutive single quotes is an escape for a single quote, therefore your command is `'[ '` you closed the string here. Then you continue: `'''--''' ]'` which means that without using any concatenation in the command you closed and opened a string. The correct way is `'[ ''--'' ]'`. About the disconnect, it may be related with the string malformation

Comment: @JorgeCampos I am using the Oracle q operator, so it's valid. Search google for "oracle q operator".

Comment: Your anonymous block works for me on 11.2.0.4 with PL/SQL Developer. What happens if you run the anonymous block in SQL*Plus? Also, it would be worth checking (or getting your DBA to check) the alert log to see if there's an entry that corresponds to your sessions termination. I've had it before where the alert log has the ORA-600 error details which weren't relayed back to the session that was terminated.

Comment: Well, I didn't knew it. Thanks. But even though judging by the list of commands that is accepted and those that are not, I still think the at least the console is not processing the q operator.

Comment: @Boneist I get the disconnect regardless of my program.

Comment: @JorgeCampos I still get the error for valid commands that don't use the q operator, e.g. `exec dbms_output.put_line(''''||''||'''');`, it's just that it's easier to go through test cases with q.

Comment: @JorgeCampos I doubt that the issue is the q operator, since if the program couldn't process it, you'd likely get an error thrown by the software itself, or a syntax error thrown by Oracle if the client was too old (which it doesn't look like it is).

Comment: @Tom I can only recommend searching the alert log for corresponding entries then.

Comment: Hmm, ok then. Maybe you can also try this question on https://dba.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: Tried to execute on 11.2.0.3.0 and 12.2.0.1.0, both 64bit and running on Windows. Connection is not dropped. Anyway, if a connection is dropped, it has nothing to do with the client. Some serious error must have happened in the Oracle session, Checking the alert and other server log is good start.
Can you reproduce the error on another Oracle instance?

Comment: @KFx I can reproduce the error on any database (tried on at least 5). I suspect it could be something to do with the network or firewall.

Comment: Also see MOS note 1506805.1, particularly section C, for how to investigate further. Can you reproduce from other clients, as well as to other DBs? Possibly en environment issue on your PC, or an odd setting on your DBs - perhaps an unusual init setting set in response to an earlier support issue? As no-one else can replicate though, you might need to raise an SR.

Comment: @Tom: what happens if you execute it locally on the server, from sqlplus? (if you are not familiar with sqlplus: execute 'set serveroutput on' in sqlplus before running the dbms_output calls.)

Comment: @KFx that's what I have been doing - my first code block is copied and pasted from my sqlplus session.

Comment: Found this: http://dbafoiz.blogspot.hu/2015/01/tns-12535-tnsoperation-timed-out-with.html
The sqlnet error structure seems the same (main error code 12535, etc.). Is it possible that a triple apostrophe triggered the firewall to terminate the connection as some sort of anti-intrusion measure?

Comment: @KFx I think that's plausible - I have raised a ticket with our network team. Could be some firewall rule on port 1521 that only affects oracle.